# How to get piped input in windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to use command like `xxx yyy | deal_everyline.bat`, where the command `xxx yyy` will generate some output. When I use `deal_everyline.bat` in console, everything runs normally. However, when I test it with `cat A.txt | deal_everyline.bat`, it only output the first line. What should I do to get all lines?

```
@echo off
:loop
set input=
set /p input=
if "%input%" neq "" (
    echo %input%
    goto loop
)
```

Comment: `for /f "tokens=*" %%$ in ('more') do echo %%$`

Answer (score 2):

penknife suggests using `MORE` with `FOR /F`, but that will corrupt tabs, and it hangs at 64K lines of input. Better to use `FINDSTR "^"`. The odd FOR /F options syntax is a way to disable both the `EOL` and `DELIMS` options so that non-blank lines are preserved exactly, as long as they are < ~8191 bytes long.

```
@echo off
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('findstr "^"') do (
  echo(%%A
)
```

The above code will skip empty lines. If you want to preserve them, then use the FINDSTR /N option to prefix each line with the line number followed by a colon, save the value in an environment variable, and then use variable expansion to strip the prefix. Variables must be expanded with delayed expansion within the FOR loop, but delayed expansion cannot be enabled when `%%A` is expanded, else it will corrupt `!` characters. So the delayed expansion is toggled on and off within the loop

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('findstr /n "^"') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
  echo(!ln!
  endlocal
)
```

If you want to preserve environment variable changes across iterations, then CALL out to a subroutine with delayed expansion constantly off. But beware that normal percent expansion of variables can fail depending on the content. For example unquoted `<`, `>`, `&`, and `|` will all cause problems.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('findstr /n "^"') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  call :processLine
)
exit /b

:processLine
set "ln=%ln:*:=%"
echo(%ln%
exit /b
```