# Capturing true STDIN piped to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, stdin

I want to access STDIN from inside a batch file **after** some other commands. I know that the first command in a .BAT file receives STDIN but I want to first run some other commands *and then* capture STDIN. I also want this to work with streamed STDIN i.e. it is not acceptable to capture STDIN to a file at the start with (see workaround below).

Now, I understand that `CON` is the "file" representing STDIN and that `TYPE CON` would output (echo) STDIN. This does not seem to work at all inside a batch file. Indeed, it appears not to represent STDIN but user/host input by keyboard.

**test.bat**

```
TYPE CON > output.txt
```

**Test run:**

```
C:>TYPE myfile.txt | test.bat
```

Expected result: `myfile.txt` is copied into `output.txt`.

Actual result: The batch waits for user input (ignores what is piped to it) and writes user input typed on the keyboard to `output.txt`.

**Workaround**

As a workaround: the following `test.bat` works but does not support streamed input (e.g. from a `tail` command):

```
findstr "^" STDIN.txt
:: I can now run some other commands
:: And finally access my STDIN via STDIN.txt
TYPE STDIN.txt | AWK /e/ > output.txt
```

**UPDATE: Back Story:**
I have a neat CMD which uses powershell to download (via HTTP) an arbitrary .ps1 script (like a package manager would) and execute it on the fly. If I call `REMEXEC.bat mymodule foo bar` it loads and executes `mymodule.ps1` with the parameters `foo` and `bar`.

This works wonderfully for every scenario except piped, streamed input. Using the `findstr "^"` works for piped input but not for an open stream. Using say `AWK /.*/` as the first line of my BAT gets me that streamed input but just pushes the problem down the road.

Ultimately I want a `something.bat` which looks like this (pseudocode):

```
downloadPSModule( "http://myrepo.com/modules/%1.ps1" )
STDIN | executePSModule %2 %3 %4
```

The catch 22 is that `downloadPSModule` happens BEFORE `executePSModule` and thus has no access to STDIN (a privelege reserved for the first line of a BAT).

Comment: Did you see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522438/how-can-a-batch-file-read-piped-input-and-write-the-result-to-a-file)? And this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575812/how-to-get-piped-input-in-windows-batch-file)?

Comment: I think it would be easier for us to assist you if you were to provide the specific task, with the actual executables, commands and code.

Comment: Yes, I've got that info @Squashman, there seems to be no way to access STDIN (CON is it not).

Comment: @Compo, I have added some back story.

Comment: *Actual result: The batch waits for user input (ignores what is piped to it) and writes user input typed on the keyboard to output.txt.* Yep that is right and you are telling to take what you type and put it in a file. Press Ctrl + Z to tell it when you have finished typing your file.

Comment: *The catch 22 is that downloadPSModule happens BEFORE executePSModule and thus has no access to STDIN (a privelege reserved for the first line of a BAT).* is also wrong. Your concepts don't align with the real world.

Comment: Thanks, your comments have helped me not a bit.

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/NTDocumentation/Windows_NT_Shell_Scripting_djvu.txt

Comment: @Marc I guess I don't understand because the code in both links consume standard input.

Comment: Neither of the links is able to capture STDIN (not console input) AFTER executing something else (say POWERSHELL).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to retrieve input from console or isolate reading from the stdin stream to not consume piped data, I would try directly reading from console with something like

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Part that reads from console, not piped input
    < con (
        set "data="
        set /p "data=Type something: "
    )

    echo(
    echo You have typed: [%data%]
    echo(

    rem Part that reads piped input
    find /v ""
```

When executed

```
W:\>type test.cmd | test.cmd
Type something: this is a test

You have typed: [this is a test]

@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Part that reads from console, not piped input
    < con (
        set "data="
        set /p "data=Type something: "
    )

    echo(
    echo You have typed: [%data%]
    echo(

    rem Part that reads piped input
    find /v ""
```

Comment: I definitely don't want to read from the console - I want the piped, stream of input.

Comment: @Marc, I'm not sure I'm understanding the problem. This code just shows that  there is not any problem to retrieve the piped data after executing another code. Just ensure your "initial" commands don't consume the piped data by assigning a different input source. That way the piped data will be available for the "final" command that reads it. Is it not the problem to solve?